# regex pattern won't return in python script

Tags: python, regex

Why does the first snippet return digits, but the latter does not? I have tried more complicated expressions without success.  The expressions I use are valid according to pythex.org, but do not work in the script.

`(\d{6}-){7}\d{6})` is one such expression.  I've tested it against this string: `123138-507716-007469-173316-534644-033330-675057-093280`

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('(\d{1})')

load_file = open('demo.txt', 'r')
search_file = load_file.read()

result = pattern.findall(search_file)

print(result)
```

==============

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('(\d{6})')

load_file = open('demo.txt', 'r')
search_file = load_file.read()

result = pattern.findall(search_file)

print(result)
```

When I put the string into a variable and then search the variable it works just fine.  This should work as is.  But it doesn't help if I want to read a text file.  I've tried to read each line of the file and that seems to be where the script breaks down.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('((\d{6}-){7})')
#pattern = re.compile('(\d{6})')

#load_file = open('demo.txt', 'r')
#search_file = load_file.read()

test_string = '123138-507716-007469-173316-534644-033330-675057-093280'

result = pattern.findall(test_string)


print(result)
```

=========
printout,
**Search File:** 
ÿþB i t L o c k e r   D r i v e   E n c r y p t i o n   R e c o v e r y   K e y

T h e   r e c o v e r y   k e y   i s   u s e d   t o   r e c o v e r   t h e   d a t a   o n   a   B i t L o c k e r   p r o t e c t e d   d r i v e .

T o   v e r i f y   t h a t   t h i s   i s   t h e   c o r r e c t   r e c o v e r y   k e y   c o m p a r e   t h e   i d e n t i f i c a t i o n   w i t h   w h a t   i s   p r e s e n t e d   o n   t h e   r e c o v e r y   s c r e e n .

R e c o v e r y   k e y   i d e n t i f i c a t i o n :   f f s d f a - f s d f - s f

F u l l   r e c o v e r y   k e y   i d e n t i f i c a t i o n :   8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 - 8 8 8 8 - 8 8 8 8 - 8 8 8 8 - 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8

B i t L o c k e r   R e c o v e r y   K e y :

1 1 1 1 1 1 - 1 1 1 1 1 1 - 1 1 1 1 1 1 - 1 1 1 1 1 1 - 1 1 1 1 1 1 - 1 1 1 1 1 1 - 1 1 1 1 1 1 - 1 1 1 1 1 1

6 6 6 6 6 6 
**Search Results:** 
[]

Process finished with exit code 0

================
This is where I ended up.  It finds the string just fine and without the commas.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('(\w{6}-\w{6}-\w{6}-\w{6}-\w{6}-\w{6}-\w{6}-\w{6})')

load_file = open('demo3.txt', 'r')

for line in load_file:
    print(pattern.findall(line))
```

Comment: When working with regular expressions, it's often useful to start by trial-and-error on a shell (run `python` and try your regex against manually crafted strings), and then making a list of a few typical cases to run the regex against automatically. By running it against a file, you're not seeing everything at the same time

Comment: There must be a typo somewhere. The regex [works](https://regex101.com/r/uM6jK4/1).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what is going wrong for you? Your second block of example code (when modified to match against the example string you give, instead of reading from a file) works as expected for me. Please make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses in this regex: `(\d{6}-){7}\d{6})`

Comment: why dont you print search_file and paste it? as it appears on the interpreter console?

Comment: Does your file actually have all those spaces in it?

Comment: well as you can see you have spaces between the digits so the regex won't match anything. what program are you using to create the file? you are having funny problems with encodings :D

Comment: anyway if all you care is retrieving those key just do `search_file = search_file.replace(' ' , '')` and then do findall()

Comment: I'm using pycharm.

Comment: After toying with this for a while i recreated the txt files as they began putting out some rather weird garbage.  Things started to work after this.  I'm not sure if its due to the fact that my files are being saved on dropbox.  the expression works, now I just need to refine it a little.  Thanks.